# Filtering through images in a pictureBox?

Tags: c#, image, forms, visual-studio, picturebox

unfortunately I don't have have enough +reputation to post an image of my windows form but i'll try to explain.

I have a pictureBox with 8 imported image to the project resources file and two buttons that i want to use to cycle back and forth through the 8 images, one button called "next" and the other button called "previous". I have seen multiple videos online explaining how to press a button and display an image allocated to that button, but can't seem to find any help with using a button to cycle through the images that have been imported for use with the pictureBox

I hope my question is clear and i look forward to reading your advice, thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to iterate through the collection of resources 1 item at a time.  I'll try to put up an example here in a few mins.  Basically, you need to get the indexes of the resource collection (if it isn't already an indexed collection, then you'll need to create one using the resources as the source) then, just increment or decrement the current index by 1 to get the string path and set it to the pictureBox image path.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ImageList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist(v=vs.110).aspx) and set a Int variable under your form as Index to loop through. And your button action would be changing index and update pictureBox image.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace imagesPictureBox
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int _currentIndex = 0;
        int currentIndex {
            get {
                return _currentIndex;
            }
            set {
                if (value >= imageList1.Images.Count) {
                    //    if index is out of range in the large side, reset to 0
                    _currentIndex = 0;
                }
                else if (value < 0) {
                    //    if index is out of range in the samll side, reset to number of images - 1 (it's 0 based)
                    _currentIndex = imageList1.Images.Count - 1;
                } else {
                    _currentIndex = value;
                }
                //    update image after index is updated
                pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[_currentIndex];
            }
        }
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[currentIndex];
        }

        private void nextBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            currentIndex++;
        }

        private void prevBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            currentIndex--;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Resources;
using System.Collections;

namespace PicBoxIteration
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ResourceSet resourceSet;
        IDictionaryEnumerator iDict;
        Dictionary<int, Bitmap> imgDict = new Dictionary<int, Bitmap>();
        int currentIndex = 0;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resourceSet =     Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);
            iDict = resourceSet.GetEnumerator();
            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
            {
                imgDict.Add(currentIndex, (Bitmap) entry.Value);  
                currentIndex ++;
            }
            currentIndex = 0;
            pictureBox1.Image = imgDict[currentIndex];

        }

        private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (currentIndex < imgDict.Count - 1)
            {
                currentIndex++;


            }
            else
            {
                currentIndex = 0;
            }
            pictureBox1.Image = imgDict[currentIndex];
        }

        private void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (currentIndex > 0)
            {
                currentIndex--;
            }
            else
            {
                currentIndex = imgDict.Count -1;
            }
            pictureBox1.Image = imgDict[currentIndex];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a crude example and may have some redundant/costly methods.  I simply threw it together as fast as I could to get you a sample of how you might itereate through these files.  Another way you may want to approach this, is to store the files in a separate folder and use the System.IO namespace to grab the files.  Just a thought.